# how to make rows and columns of the same image using JS?

Tags: javascript

I would like a picture to appear x number of times in rows and columns. So if I'm creating a multiplication game and the question is "What is 9 x 5?", how do I ensure my 200x200 photo appears 45 times in 9 columns and 5 rows using vanilla JS? I figure I need to make a table, but don't know how to do that based on what the two numbers are.

```
let one = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;
let two = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;
let photos = document.getElementById('photos');

let product = one * two;
let productNum = parseInt(product);

const img = new Image();
const imgSrc = x.jpg;

function generateImage() {
  const img = document.createElement('img')
  img.src = imgSrc;
  return img;
}

for (let i = 0; i < productNum; i++ ) {
   photos.appendChild(generateImage());
}
```

Comment: Create a `table` element like you created an `img` element then add row and columns, html doc [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table). Do you need help to make loops ?

Comment: a grid layout would also work https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a function like this:

```js
function createTable(w, h, src) {
    let table = document.createElement('table');
    for(let i = 0; i < h; ++i) {
        let row = table.insertRow();
        for(let j = 0; j < w; ++j) {
            let td = row.insertCell();
            let img = document.createElement('img');
            img.setAttribute('src', src);
            td.appendChild(img);
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('photos').appendChild(table);
}

createTable(9, 5, 'https://i.imgur.com/DfEE9nm.png');
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id='photos'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfect. Plus One.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would probably be to create a div for each row and add images to each row to make up the columns.

```js
let one = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;
let two = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;
let photos = document.getElementById("photos");

let product = one * two;
let productNum = parseInt(product);

const imgSrc = "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196";

function generateImage() {
  const img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = imgSrc;
  return img;
}

const rows = one;
const columns = two;

for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  const rowDiv = document.createElement("div");
  for (let j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
    rowDiv.appendChild(generateImage());
  }

  photos.appendChild(rowDiv);
}
```

```html
<div id="photos"></div>
```